# Check for extension changed file type before upload in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image, file, image-uploading

I'm working with file upload and crop in php and jquery. Now I got a problem that if file type is changed from any other to image file type then my code throws valid file type and in php while cropping it can't get that file as image and it can't crop and throws error. So how can I check for modified extensions that is the uploaded file is actually an image file.

jquery:

```
             var oFReader = new FileReader();
            var file = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];

          var fileType = file.type;
          alert(fileType);
          var ValidImageTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"];
          if ($.inArray(fileType, ValidImageTypes) < 0) {
          alert('invalid file type');
           }
         else{    
            //stuff to crop the image
          }
```

This only checks for image files its nice, but if .doc extension is changed to .png extension and tried to upload it treats it as image file. So how can I detect that if the file is actually an image file.

Comment: changing the extension it means convert into another type. `.doc` ext is changed to `.png` it will always be image type.

Comment: @Noman exactly, if ext is changed it becomes image type but it is not the image file in actual, which I want to detect that is the uploaded file is actually image file or not

Comment: please upload your file which you say it is not the actual image file.